# What are the most common uses for Entity Framework Complex Types?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using the Entity Framework and am considering using Complex types for some common fields across tables eg: CreatedDate, LastUpdatedDate, CreatedBy, LastUpdatedBy etc. (not sure what to call the complex type in this case? any ideas)

I assume this is a good candidate for using a Copmlex Type, primarily because its easy to copy and past the Type to new entities and creating custom methods to populate these types etc?

I am using Model First Approach and trying not to introduce stored procedures in the database to having complex types that can be used for calculated values etc will not be used.

What other common uses are there for complex types, would be great to get some examples of how people use them.

Your comments appreciated.

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a completely valid programming question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Complex type you can unit common entities so that you dont have to go to multiple entities.

Another useful use of Complex type is you can import stored procedure to complex type.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am using a complex type in a current project to seamlessly decrypt certain fields in a database table using a stored procedure. This allows me to store the data encrypted, and keep the encryption details out of my application and instead down at the database layer.